# Where are BPCs Delivered from Mobile Laboratories?

Tags: eve-online

When you complete a research job, like copying, at a mobile laboratory, at a POS, where are the resultant copies or researched blueprint delivered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are inside the POS module itself. So you need to;

- Complete (or 'deliver') the job
- Undock and take a (small) ship and actually fly close to the module.
- Right click on the module and 'open' it
- Profit

Answer (score 1):

Copies are inside the POS module, but time efficiency and material efficiency research are returned to their original location.